# Identifying the clicker

Tags: identify

So i want to create a website, where people can chose from 4 topic. The fastest one who clicks a topic gets it, and everyone can only chose 1 topic. (the topics are in a clickable div.) After someone chose a topic, by clicing on it  that topic gets removed from the picking list. Now i need a way to identify who was the one, who clicked the topic. I actually dont have ANY of this website yet, im just planning, and i thought of this and found no solution. The website is going to have registration and login, so thats how i want to identify the cilcker. I dont kow if you guys get it, and i know that usually people come here with a half dont code that just needs a word or so changed, and what im asking now is no where close to that. Hope some1 can help, thanks.

Comment: Good idea. Start implementing it.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question to meet the standards outlined there.